# TimesTen JDBC URL format without DSN

Tags: jdbc, timesten

I would like to ask what should be the format of JDBC URL when I know the server OP, port, user and password. I cannot use ODBC (DSN).

I have tried: `jdbc:timesten:client://<server>:<port>/<db>`, but it is not working.

Comment: How you checked what the [TimesTen documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTJDV/writing_app.htm#TTJDV130) says about possible URL formats? It only lists DSN support, so it seems you cannot use anything else.

Comment: I have checked the documentation and I didn't find what I was looking for there. After a lot of hours I was able to find the solution I was looking for. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I could not find it anywhere I was able to get it working by trying huge amount of options. To save others some time, here is what worked for me.

`jdbc:timesten:client:TTC_SERVER=<server>;TCP_PORT=<port>;TTC_SERVER_DSN=<DB name>;`